# Is there any way to render HTML in ActionScript3 - FlashPlayer SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I already know about StageWebView and HTMLLoader, but that only works in Adobe AIR. Is there any way (maybe third party) to do the same in a SWF.

**Reason:**

I'm building a game in AS3 that will run on mobile devices with Adobe AIR, and there is also a web version that will run as a SWF.

The game has some links, URLs that open in a StageWebView for mobile. My problem is that the SWF has to open these URLs in a browser popup or i-frame... I don't like it :(

Comment: So you want to have a browser with html with a flash inside that has a browser component to run html?

Comment: @MarkKnol: Yes, that's right... Probably too much to ask. I need to have HTML content displayed within the flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish isn't possible in a SWF. However, on the web you will have access to javascript and HTML, and with that, you could replicate the functionality with an iframe that sits directly over your SWF.